# Running python functions in Eclipse command line

Tags: python, eclipse, command-line

I would like to run a python function using the command line in Eclipse (if it exists), just like the normal Python Shell (IDLE) or programs such as MATLAB. How would I do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), which is a plugin for running Python programs from Eclipse.  Once installed, you'll have the option of running the applications themselves or loading the PyDev console which gives you the functionality you're inquiring about.

Comment: Thanks, I should have put more in the question. I already installed PyDev but I didn't know it had a console :S. I also managed to get the normal python console to work using the "External Tool Configuration" although I prefer the PyDev console, at least the command history works. Thanks a lot.

Sorry I had to delete the last comment, typos :D